# Synchronous RestAPI with AWS API gateway and express stepfunctions

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

i am not able to invoke express stepfunction using restapi apigateway action type with StartSyncExecution

thanks in advance

Comment: can you add what you have tried so far, some code/templates/screenshots and what is the error you are facing, etc?

Comment: when i was hitting from api gate way it was giving 400 error , i was able to execute same flow with async flow it works great but not with sync flow.

Comment: you are using HTTP Api or REST Api?

Comment: i am using restapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only HTTP API is currently supported, in order to invoke a step function using StartSyncExecution, you need to use the HTTP API.

Edit: It is now supported per the document in the comment below.

Comment: now aws has sync execution on REST API's
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/05/amazon-api-gateway-rest-apis-integrates-with-step-funtions-synchronous-express-workflows/